# How to create TLS client in react native?

Tags: react-native

Currently I am using AXIOS in my react-native app to make calls to http API servers, however now i need to use HTTPS with TLS connection to my API Server. How can i configure a client in React-Native to use my keystore.jks and truststore.jks to be able to communicate with my server?

Regards